# Ipad to Ipad screen sharing

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, screensharing

I am planning to give a demo of my app to my clients.For that purpose i want to share my screen with the other Ipads say there will be 5 Ipads among the clients and i want to share my screen with them.

Is there any way to do that?Can anyone post something which will help me?

Thanks in advance,

Christy

Comment: Can anyone provide me a little clue please.that how  to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no app which allows for mirroring the whole iPad screen. All screen sharing apps, that currently exist mirror the content of the screensharing app, but nothing else.

No workaround, I am afraid.